# Usage of そこ with と勘違い

Tags: meaning

Context: A guy is trying to differentiate his group from an old group (nwo) because some people may think they are doing the exact same things nwo did in the past.

> 「よく『nWoジャパンと同じやないか』って、『あのパクリをしてるのか』みたいな、そんな同じようには見てほしくはないですね。『別物だよ』とそこは勘違いしていただきたくないですね。もし、思っている人がいるのであれば」

The last sentence seems to be saying: "don't confuse us as being a different thing". That sounds like: "We are not different than them" which I don't think makes sense. This is the translation from the US version:

> And I hear that a lot. About nWo Japan. “Aren’t you just an nWo ripoff?” I don’t want people to think that. If anybody does I want to let them know we’re a different thing.’

Is there something omitted? what's そこ referring to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's from an interview, so (as you might have noticed) its grammar is a bit iffy. I think you can understand it like...

> 『別物だよ』と（いうふうに考えて/思って）、そこは勘違いしていただきたくないですね。
>   (≂ 『別物だよ』と（いうふうに考えて/思って）、そこは勘違いしないでいただきたいですね。)

Literally: "I want them to think 'They're a different thing', and don't want them to misunderstand on that point."

I think the そこは is like "regarding that" or "on that point" (≂「その点は」).